# Postgresql HA by Bitnami - Unable to get session context error when trying to create a db from a .NET app

Tags: postgresql, session, high-availability, pgpool, sessioncontext

I deployed Postgresql HA Helm Chart by Bitnami on my Kubernetes Cluster and did the configuration based on the provided configuration fields by the Helm chart. I'm getting an error when trying to create a db from a .NET app when using PgPool II's connection string. The error says "PID XXX Unable to get session context".

My app first creates a db if it does not exist and then migrates the data. I should mention that if I manually create the db, then the app migrates the data without problem, which proves that the connection string is correct. I tried connecting directly to Postgresql server, skipping the PgPool, and the app created the db and migrated it which I believe that the app is working as expected. I used a superuser when I tried all of these things.

This is my pg_hba.conf

```
host     all            repmgr    0.0.0.0/0    trust
host     repmgr         repmgr    0.0.0.0/0    trust
host     repmgr         repmgr    ::/0    trust
host     replication      repmgr    0.0.0.0/0    trust
host     replication      repmgr    ::/0    trust
#hostssl     all             all             0.0.0.0/0               cert
#hostssl     all             all             ::/0                    cert
host     all              all       0.0.0.0/0    trust
host     all              all       ::/0         trust
local    all              all                    trust
```

This is my pool_hba.conf

```
local    all             all                            trust
host     all             repmgr       all         trust
host     all             aio       all         scram-sha-256
host     all             wide               all         trust
host     all             pop_user           all         trust
host     all             all                all         scram-sha-256
```

Is it possible that I should modify the code when connecting to a connection pooler as opposed to connecting to a postgresql server to get the session context?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check your database name if its include uppercase letters change them all to lowercase letters .